# De-encode URL parameters

Tags: python, django, web-services, url

I am talking to a server that used to send me HTTP strings like this:

```
/path/to/my/handler/?action-query&id=112&type=vca&info=ch=0&type=event&ev16[sts=begin (...)
```

So the "info" GET parameter included "=" and "&" characters. It was rather unorthodox but nevertheless we wrote a parser for it. However, recently they have decided to encode part of it, so now the string looks like this..

```
/path/to/my/handler/?action=query&id=112&type=vca&info=ch%3D0%26type%3Devent%26ev46[sts%3Dbegin (...)
```

This breaks our parser, which expects a string like the first one.

Can I somehow "de-encode" the string, so that I can use the old code (so that it's not broken as we re-write the parser)?

As per answer below, we can use urllib.unquote() to clean the string up. However, we are relying on request.GET, which gets set up based on the first string. Is it possible to reconstruct the GET object based on the new converted string, or somehow force it to re-evaluate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect what you want is the `unquote` function from the `urllib` module.

```
>>> s = '/path/to/my/handler/?action=query&id=112&type=vca&info=ch%3D0%26type%3Devent%26ev46[sts%3Dbegin'
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote(s)
'/path/to/my/handler/?action=query&id=112&type=vca&info=ch=0&type=event&ev46[sts=begin'
```

Edit: I'm not very familiar with Django, but the [Request and response object section of their docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) states the following:

> QueryDict instances are immutable, unless you create a copy() of them. That means you can't change attributes of request.POST and request.GET directly.

Based on my limited reading of those docs, you might be able to apply the `unquote()` function to the `HttpRequest.body` attribute and build a new `QueryDict` out of the results (and possibly use it to update your current one if necessary).

Comment: Yes, this does get rid of the encoded characters. Any suggestion on how I could make the request.GET behave as if it received the unquoted string?

Comment: @Goro, see the edit to my original answer. I'm not a Django guru, so you may wish to wait for one of them to chime in.