# Urldecode GET parameter in django

Tags: django, urldecode

I have a `GET` parameter of value `Krak%F3w`. It should be decoded as Kraków. I tried to `urlunquote` it, but when I try to print it to the console, I get this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /someurl.html

'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

And this:

```
Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Krak�w
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215298/de-encode-url-parameters

Comment: That's not a correct encoding. It should be `Krak%C3%B3w`.

Comment: According to this site, it's ok: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: @MarekMałek Not according to any encoder I've tested. Python: `urllib.quote("Kraków")`, JavaScript: `encodeURIComponent("Kraków")`.

Comment: Then maybe it's in some strange encoding :/. Thanks anyway, you can post your comments as answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding seems to be `iso-8859-2`, so you need to decode it:

```
url=urllib.unquote(url).decode('iso-8859-2')
```

Comment: Now when I print it, I get: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @MarekMałek are you using windows?