# Python / Django: Get var from cookies

Tags: python, django, mixpanel

I tried to get `distinct_id` with `request.COOKIES.get('distinct_id')`. However Mixpanel saves the data in a not extractable way for me. Anyone knows why there are all these `%22%3A%20%22` and how to extraxt distinct_id?

`print(request.COOKIES)`:

```
{
'djdt': 'hide',
'cookie_bar': '1',
'mp_1384c4d0e46aaaaad007e3d8b5d6eda_mixpanel': '%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22165edf326870-00fc0e7eb72ed3-34677908-fa000-165e40c268947b%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22__alias%22%3A%20%22maz%2B1024%40gmail.com%22%7D',
'csrftoken': 'nvWzsrp3t6Sivkrsyu0gejjjjjiTfc36ZfkH7U7fgHaI40EF',
'sessionid': '7bkel6r27ebd55x262cv9lzv61gzoemw'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code. You can run it because use the example you shared. First you must unquote the data in the mixpanel value. I used the suffix of the cookie key to get it. Then after the unquote you must load the json to get back a dictionary.

The code here prints all the keys in the dictionary, but you can easily get the `distinct_id` using `mixpanel_dict.get('distinct_id')`

Try it.

```
from urllib import parse
import json

cookie = {'djdt': 'hide',
'cookie_bar': '1',
'mp_1384c4d0e46aaaaad007e3d8b5d6eda_mixpanel': '%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22165edf326870-00fc0e7eb72ed3-34677908-fa000-165e40c268947b%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22__alias%22%3A%20%22maz%2B1024%40gmail.com%22%7D',
'csrftoken': 'nvWzsrp3t6Sivkrsyu0gejjjjjiTfc36ZfkH7U7fgHaI40EF',
'sessionid': '7bkel6r27ebd55x262cv9lzv61gzoemw'
}


def get_value_for_mixpanel(cookie):
    mixpanel_dict = {}
    for key in cookie.keys():
        if '_mixpanel' in key:
            value = parse.unquote(cookie.get(key))
            mixpanel_dict = json.loads(value)
    return mixpanel_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mixpanel_dict = get_value_for_mixpanel(cookie) # type: dict
    for key,value in mixpanel_dict.items():
        print("%s:%s" %(key, value))
```

Result

```
distinct_id:165edf326870-00fc0e7eb72ed3-34677908-fa000-165e40c268947b
$initial_referrer:$direct
$initial_referring_domain:$direct
__alias:maz+1024@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `unquote()`

```
>>> s = '/path/to/my/handler/?action=query&id=112&type=vca&info=ch%3D0%26type%3Devent%26ev46[sts%3Dbegin'
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote(s)
>>> '/path/to/my/handler/?action=query&id=112&type=vca&info=ch=0&type=event&ev46[sts=begin'
```

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11215316/5647272

Comment: That's already some progress. I now get it back like attached, but it is a string and I can't access distinct_id as in a dict. Do you know how to make it a dict? `{"distinct_id": "165e40caaaaaaa-a-2ed3-34677908-fa000-165e40c268947b","$initial_referrer": "$direct","$initial_referring_domain": "$direct","__alias": "maz@gmail.com"}`

Comment: Did you tried something like `decoded_data["mp_1384c4d0e46aaaaad007e3d8b5d6eda_mixpanel"]["distinct_id"]` ?